# Exporting spatial data linkage from two inputs in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3

I have a csv file containing of points (house locations) and shapefiles consisting of polygons (congressional districts)

How do I export a csv of the points and what district that point falls in?

Because I don't have any objective id for the points so I was unable to use join data feature in [Exporting query to identify what polygon certain points fall in using ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/18153/78590).

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do the following, assuming the CSV file has X,Y locations

1. Add the CSV file as point data
2. Go to `File -> Add data -> Add X,Y Data`
3. Save point data as feature class (shapefile) by right-click on the point data -> Data -> Export data
4. Add the district polygons and the newly created point shapefile (houses), then right-click the point shapefile -> `Join and Relate -> Join` -> Use "Join data from another layer based on spatial location" -> Use "It falls inside" -> Save the results to a new shapefile
5. Load the newly created shapefile with the joined information -> open the attribute table -> Go to table option (White sheet icon at the top left corner) -> go to Export -> Choose "Text" under the Save as Type. It will Create a CSV file with point data and the districts information.

If you need more options, then you can use ArcToolbox -> Analysis Tools -> Overlay -> Open Spatial Join

1. Use point shapefile (houses) for Target Feature
2. Use district polygons for Join Feature
3. Join_One_to_One
4. You can use Field Mapping, if necessary, or keep the default option
5. Use Intersect as match option, or choose the option that is suitable to your case
6. Save to a new shapefile
7. Load the newly created shapefile with the joined information -> open the attribute table -> Go to table option (White sheet icon at the top left corner) -> go to Export -> Choose Text under the Save as Type. It will Create a CSV file with point data and the districts information.

Comment: Thanks, the first option works. I didn't manage to find export text option so I saved as dbf then changed the extension to csv.